# Facebook login in Spring boot application, redirects to www.example.com:8080 automatically

Tags: facebook, spring-mvc, spring-boot, facebook-login, spring-social-facebook

I am implementing login with facebook in my spring boot application using simple`action="/signin/facebook" method="POST"` as given in spring docs.
So after succesfull login control is getting redirected automatically to www.example.com:8080 instead of www.example.com.
So please could anyone help me resolving this issue?

**EDIT**
I am Following the below example for social login with facebook using spring
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-samples/tree/master/spring-social-showcase-boot
Following the code

spring boot version: 1.2.4

Following the html form

```
<form name="fb_signin" id="fb_signin" th:action="@{/signin/facebook}" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" th:value="${_csrf.token}"></input>
    <input type="hidden" name="scope" value="publish_stream,user_photos,offline_access"></input>
    <button type="submit"><img th:src="@{/social/facebook/sign-in-with-facebook.png}"></img></button>
</form>
```

Following the controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/signup", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public SignupForm signupForm(WebRequest request) {
    Connection<?> connection = providerSignInUtils.getConnectionFromSession(request);
    if (connection != null) {
        request.setAttribute("message", new Message(MessageType.INFO, "Your " + StringUtils.capitalize(connection.getKey().getProviderId()) + " account is not associated with a Spring Social Showcase account. If you're new, please sign up."), WebRequest.SCOPE_REQUEST);
        return SignupForm.fromProviderUser(connection.fetchUserProfile());
    } else {
        return new SignupForm();
    }
}
```

Comment: [Same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32056102/spring-boot-login-with-facebook-it-is-redirect-with-port-number-ex-http-examp) from a different user? Post configuration and code, what have you tried, how are you entering your application. Which version of Spring Social Facebook you are using...

Comment: please check above edited version of question for more details.

Comment: we are following follwing example for facebook social login with spring
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-samples/tree/master/spring-social-showcase-boot